# How to Lock or password protected specific cell in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

How can I Lock a specific cell in a sheet of excel 2010 so that any one can not change or input anything in that cell?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all cells by `Ctrl + A`
2. Right click on any cell and select "Format Cells"
3. Go to "Protection" Tab and uncheck "Locked", Press OK
4. Select the cell that you want to lock or hold down `Ctrl` to select multiple cells, right click on one of the selected cell and select "Format Cells"
5. Go to "Protection" Tab and check "Locked", Press OK
6. Go to "Review" Tab and click on "Protect Sheet", enter password, re enter password, press OK.
7. You're done!